# Launchd plist task python sys.path error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, plist, launchd

I'm trying to build a daily scheduled plist task using launchd that loads a python script that sends me an email containing a link via sendgrid.

My python script to send the email works from the command line with `python dailyemail.py` (see below)

```
import os, requests, bs4, sendgrid
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *
url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html'
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("xxx")
to_email = Email("xxx")
subject = "Astronomy Picture of the Day"
content = Content("text/plain", 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html')
mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

When I load and start my plist task it runs at the specified time, but fails due to not being able to import the `requests, bs4 and sendgrid` modules. 
From logging the `sys.path` outputs, I have identified that my system seems to be loading two subtly different versions of Python from the command line vs when I run the task via launchd (see output at end and plist task).

I have two questions:

1. How do I resolve this disparity? Also interested to understand why
   these file paths would be different?
2. Is there another way to load / reference python modules into a plist task to get it working?

Thanks!

**System: OSX El Capitan 10.11.3**

**Plist task**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <!-- The label should be the same as the filename without the extension -->
    <string>com.alexanderhandy.nasa</string>
    <!-- Specify how to run your program here -->
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/alexanderhandy/Documents/Programming/Scripts/dailyemail.py</string>
    </array>
    <!-- Run every dat -->
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/ahnasa.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/ahnasa.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
      <dict>
          <key>Hour</key>
          <integer>12</integer>
          <key>Minute</key>
          <integer>34</integer>
      </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Error logs**

```
*Command line python sys.path*
 /Users/alexanderhandy/Documents/Programming/Scripts/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-17.0-py2.7.egg/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

*plist task python sys.path*
/Users/alexanderhandy/Documents/Programming/Scripts/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not 100% sure here so others are welcomed to improve upon this answer.

-

Reading up on system.path for Python2.7 in the relevant [PythonDocs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.path) and then interpreting the output it gives it seems that your commandline script version of Python is unstalled under `/usr/local/lib`, meaning it's a local install while LaunchDaemon is running a system based install located within the `/System/Library/Frameworks/` folder.

My hunch is you might have installed your Python2.7 via Homebrew, causing you to end up with 2 different versions of Python. There are many relevant questions/answers upon the possible up- and downsides of this all over StackOverflow. You've probably installed your modules against Homebrew's version, yet LaunchDaemon is using macOS pre-installed version.

Reading the [Homebrew Docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html) on Python my next hunch would be that if you change:

`<string>/usr/bin/python</string>`

In your plist task to:

`<string>/usr/bin/python2</string>`

You should probably be fine.

If not, please let me know cause there probably are multiple ways to solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks @montmons - led me onto the right path. Solution ended up being linking directly to the Homebrew installed python bin directory in my plist ```<string>/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/bin/python2.7</string>```